# Any links on creating presentation in windbg

Tags: windbg, presentation

The one and only Sasha's tweet below shows that presentations can be created using windbg. 
https://twitter.com/goldshtn/status/672494178769719300

Anyone knows how to do that?

PS: I know Sasha is on stackoverflow, so may be he can answer this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Presentation" is somewhat of an exaggeration. What you meant to ask is "how to format output in WinDbg?"

To this the answer is "using DML".

Whether you use [`.printf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564716(v=vs.85).aspx) or send output to the debugger using [`OutputDebugString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx), you can use Debugger Markup Language (DML) to output use colors, links etc.

The tag reference is located in the page [Customizing Debugger Output Using DML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt613235(v=vs.85).aspx).

"Drawing" using monospace text is your business, however. WinDbg has no facilities to help you with that as far as I know.